# Tensor product of two polynomials

Tags: ring-theory, tensor-products

Given two polynomials $a$ and $b$ over some ring $R$, what is the explicit definition of their tensor product?

If it's easier to be more concrete, take $R=\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $p(x) = \sum a_i x^i$ and $q(x) = \sum b_j y^i$.  Then we have
$$
p(x) \otimes q(y) = \sum_{i,j} a_i b_j (x^i \otimes y^j)
$$
The tensor product of the modules $R[x] \otimes R[y]$ is the space of all polynomials of the form
$$
\sum_{i,j} c_{ij} (x^i \otimes y^j)
$$
It may be helpful to think of this as the space of polynomials of the form
$$
\sum_{i,j} c_{ij} (x^i y^j)
$$
where $x$ and $y$ are non-commuting variables.

Comment: Omnomnomnom thanks. A couple of questions for my further clarification, if you'd be so kind:
1. I presume the sum ranges over the Cartesian product of (values of) $i$ and $j$?
2. What is the definition of the $\otimes$ on the RHS?

Comment: 1: yes.  I guess you could say $i = 0,\dots,m$ and $j = 0, \dots, n$ or something of the like. 2: $v \otimes w$ is the tensor product of the vectors $v$ and $w$.  If $v$ and $w$ are "just two vectors", then $v \otimes w$ is "just their tensor product", which is a vector in a larger module.  If you want to think of this tensor product as a space of polynomials on non-commuting variables, then $\otimes$ is the product that we use for the symbols $x$ and $y$.

Comment: 1. What does non-commuting mean here? `Not necessarily commuting'?
2. Forgive me for laboring this: so for polynomials, $x^3\otimes y^4$ is just $x^3 y^4$?

Comment: Yes.  Non commuting means not commuting.  So, because $x$ and $y$ are non-commuting variables, $xy \neq yx$.  Note, then, that elements like $yx$ and $xyx^2$ are not elements of the space of polynomials that we are considering.  And yes, you can think of $x^3 \otimes y^4$ as $x^3y^4$, as long as you don't switch these to get $y^4x^3$.

Comment: So, quick warning: I assumed that you were thinking of $R[x] \otimes R[y]$ as a module as opposed to an algebra.  If you want to multiply two of these elements of these, you need this to be the [tensor product of algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_algebras).  The multiplication is a bit wonky.  In particular, we have
$$
(x^{n_1} \otimes y^{m_1})(x^{n_2} \otimes y^{m_2}) = 
x^{n_1 + n_2} \otimes y^{m_1 + m_2}
$$
which may seem weird, especially since I told you to think of $x$ and $y$ as non-commuting variables.

Comment: The key here is that even if we multiply two elements, we shouldn't end up with any product where a $y$ comes before an $x$, since we are only looking at the space of polynomials in which the $x$ comes before the $y$.

Comment: So (slightly tangentially) is the non-commutativity a result of the `quotienting' process when tensor product is considered (in Category Theory terms) as a pullback?

Comment: Not quite.  I would say, in fact, that we could only obtain commutativity if we go through another "quotienting" process to obtain the "symmetric tensor product". Also, I don't think that a tensor product can accurately be referred to as a "pullback", which is a distinct notion in category theory.

Comment: I would say that the tensor product maintains the non-commutativity of the cartesian product.

Comment: Oops, I mean pushout. See `example 6':
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushout_(category_theory)